# scripting: create an allDayEvent spanning more than one day

Tags: calendar, google-apps-script

When working with my calendar, I do the following to create an allDayEvent which spans more than one day (e.g.Vacation or scool halidays):
- I create an allDayEvent for the 1st day
- I click on the event
- now I may enter the last date and save the event.

How may I do this in a script? I may get the flag with "isAllDayEvent"; I may set a date with "setAllDayDate"; but how to set a start-date and an end-date to an AllDayEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use recurrence, see [full documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_recurrence?hl=en)

In your example it would use  [addDailyRule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_recurrence?hl=en#addDailyRule) to repeat every day and [until](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_recurrence?hl=en#until) to define endDate.

Comment: I'm trying to update a Google Calendar event to a recurring multiple all-day event so using a repeat rule to extend the event duration doesn't help.

setAllDayDate() works fine but setAllDayDates() gives a timed event starting at midnight + my GMT offset, spanning an extra day.  I can reset recurrence thanks to Serge (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35485356/283182), but I get 404 errors patching even when using the previously returned Events resource for sequence https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364004/google-calendar-api-event-update-with-the-ruby-gem and I can't find any official docs!

Comment: After more tests it turns out setAllDayDates(startDate, endDate) is correctly creating an all day event lasting several days, but then adding the recurrence with setRecurrence(recurrence, startDate, endDate); converts the event to a single timed repeat at 2am (when using GMT+2) lasting an extra day. If the UI didn't support all-day repeats which last longer than a day, I'd understand... but it does.

Comment: You will have to use the advanced calendar service for that. It basically offers all the options available in the ui.  Read this post to see how to access : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35477612/google-calendar-script-remove-recurrence/35485356#35485356

Comment: Thank you, it does indeed work as long as I use advanced calendar service to set start, end AND recurrence.