# Google Calendar script: remove recurrence

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-calendar-recurring-events

I'm iterating through a spreadsheet of events and modifying my calendar accordingly.

I can use `setRecurrence` to create multi-day events, but I can't figure out how to remove the class and turn it back into a single-day event.

It's important to know because evidently applying `setRecurrence` to an event more than once does not replace/redefine the existing recurrence, but keeps tacking additional classes onto it. This prevents simple workarounds, such as applying a recurrence of 0 days, etc.

I'm looking for the equivalent of `event.removeRecurrence()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code uses advanced Calendar service, you have to enable it in the script editor menu : ressources/advanced Google Services ***

```
function ChangeEvent(){
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var eventId = 'omv6###########e8jbs';
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId);
  Logger.log('old recurrence = '+event.recurrence);
  event.recurrence = '';
  Calendar.Events.patch(event,calendarId,eventId);
  Logger.log('new recurrence = '+event.recurrence);
}
```

---

[image]

---

### EDIT

**following your comment,**

Please note that the ID used by the advanced calendar API is slightly different as it does not include the @google.com. You should simply remove this last part before using it.

Example :

```
[16-02-19 07:22:59:739 CET] ba4a1dub73uqsvhld3abh15f38@google.com
[16-02-19 07:22:59:740 CET] ba4a1dub73uqsvhld3abh15f38
```

Use some string methods to get the result we need :

```
  Logger.log(event.getId());// event is the event you get using calendarApp
  var advancedID = event.getId().substring(0,event.getId().indexOf('@'));
  Logger.log(advancedID);// this ID is for advanced service
}
```

---

### Working example :

First create an event with a 5 days recurrence using calendarApp (so we are in your real condition) using `createEventRec()`

Check on the calendar that the event is as expected

Then use `changeEvent()` and check the result

```
function createEventRec(){
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(5);
  var event = cal.createEventSeries('Dinner with Mary', new Date(),new Date(new Date().getTime()+3600000), recurrence);
  Logger.log(event.getId());
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('ID',event.getId());
}


function ChangeEventRecurrence(){
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var ID = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('ID');
  var advancedID = ID.substring(0,ID.indexOf('@'));
  Logger.log(advancedID);
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, advancedID);
  Logger.log('old recurrence = '+event.recurrence);
  event.recurrence = '';
  Calendar.Events.patch(event,calendarId,advancedID);
  Logger.log('new recurrence = '+event.recurrence);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I now have the advanced Calendar service running, but I'm getting "Error: Exception: Not Found" using my event IDs (which look like xxx@google.com). My calendar ID (xxx@group.calendar.google.com) works fine.

Comment: See edit please. The Id is slightly different for advanced service.

Comment: Thank you again. I had tried that, but unfortunately I'm still getting an Error: Exception: Not Found. My event id now looks like: k7oh14d7**********lchssj2g. I've checked and the event does exist.

Comment: I added a working demo so you can see how it works. For the example purpose I store the ID in scriptProperties but of course you can store it in a spreadsheet as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no idea the advanced calendar API existed until today!

Answer (score 0):

```
ev.removeAllReminders();
ev.deleteEvent();
```

Answer (score 0):

This could would help you to delete events recursively from Jan 1st through 10th Jan.

```
function delete_rec_events()
{
  //take care: Date function starts at 0 for the month (January=0)
  var fromDate = new Date(2018,0,1,0,0,0); //This is January 1, 2018
  var toDate = new Date(2018,0,10,0,0,0);   //This is January 10, 2018 at 00h00'00"

  var calendarName = '<Name of the Calendar>';    
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0];
  var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);

  for(var i=0; i<events.length;i++)
  {
    var ev = events[i];
    Logger.log('Checking Event Title === ' + calendar.getEventSeriesById(ev.getId()).getTitle());
    calendar.getEventSeriesById(ev.getId()).deleteEventSeries();
    Logger.log('Event Deleted');
  }
}
```