# Google AppsScript: Remove recurring (eventSeries) from Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have the following code that removes events from my google calendar that are flagged as `Pending Removal` in google sheets. The part of this code that removes single events works just fine but I need to tweak it to remove recurring events as well. Right now it only removes the first event in the recurring event series.

Note: events are indicated as pending removal in `Column E` or ```x[4]``.
[image]

```
function calendarRemove() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Events Calendar')
  var settingsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Calendar Settings');
  var calendarId = 'calendarID';
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var eventArray = dataSheet.getRange('A2:H').getDisplayValues();

  for (x = 0; x < eventArray.length; x++) {

    var event = eventArray[x];
    var eventName = event[1];
    var eventDate = new Date(event[0]);
    var timeZone = event[6];
    var startTime = new Date(`${event[0]} ${event[2]} ${timeZone}`);
    var endTime = new Date(`${event[0]} ${event[3]} ${timeZone}`);
    var status = event[4]; // Used in the following comparison expression

    if (status === 'Pending Removal') {
      var returnedEvents = eventCal.getEventsForDay(eventDate, {search: eventName});
      for (i = 0; i < returnedEvents.length; i++) {
        var toRemove = returnedEvents[i];
        if (toRemove.isRecurringEvent) {
          toRemove.deleteEventSeries();
        } else { toRemove.deleteEvent(); }
        eventArray[x][4] = 'Removed'; // Modifying the status value from "Pending Removal" to "Removed"
      }
    }
  }
  dataSheet.getRange('A2:H').setValues(eventArray); // Overwrite the source data with the modified array
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a thread that points out that issue, where you need to remove the recurrence of the event first and then delete the rest of them in the loop on [Google Calendar script: remove recurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35477612/google-calendar-script-remove-recurrence)

This script might help you out, at the end of the previous thread

```
function deleteEvents()
{

  var calendarName = '<Name of the Calendar>';    
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0];
  var events = calendar.getEvents('<Sheet events where recurring events is set to "Yes">');

  for(var i=0; i < events.length;i++)
  {
    var ev = events[i];
    Logger.log('Checking Event Title === ' + calendar.getEventSeriesById(ev.getId()).getTitle());
    calendar.getEventSeriesById(ev.getId()).deleteEventSeries();
    Logger.log('Event Deleted');
  }
}
```